# Code, Build and Run on seperate Machines. Posssible?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, tfs, msbuild, virtual-pc

I know that I can code on one machine and have it build on a different machine (ie. a build server). Now I have also heard that you can have visual studio run a build on a virtual machine (i think it requires Virtual PC). Now my question is if anyone has been able to code on machine **A**, have it compile on machine **B** and run a debugging sesion on machine **C**?

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty common in enterprise development and just about the de facto standard way of doing things.

Typically, a dev works locally.  Once s/he is happy with their changes, they'll check it into a source control system.

From that point there are a couple of options ranging from automated building to having someone push the button to cause the remote build.

Once the build is complete there are a host of options available for deploying the app to one or more other servers.  And yet other options for kicking off automated test suites.

Concerning remote debugging, you can do that independently of whether you are using a build/deployment/automated testing.  It's just a matter of getting the right stuff installed and configured (see ho1's answer for a link).

All of that said, I highly recommend you *never* enable remote debugging on a production server.  Some people might disagree with me but I personally think it's dangerous for security reasons and can certainly lead to site outages.

Finally, the only reasons you would need a virtual machine is if the servers aren't available or if you just want to sandbox everything.

Answer (score 1):

You can do remote debugging, so if you had an automated process to copy the compiled code from B to C, I suppose you could do what you're asking.

See this MSDN article for more details: [How to: Set Up Remote Debugging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt727f1t%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)